# With $z_y = y!+2$, find $\sum_{i=3}^3 z_i$

Tags: summation

I'm lost on the factorial included here in this problem. Any help is appreciated!

sequence is $z_y= y! +2, Y \ge 1.$

Find $\sum\limits_{i=3}^3 z_i$.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please edit your post - I have no idea what you've written.

Comment: Do you really mean $\displaystyle \sum_{i=3}^{3} z_i$?

Comment: Maybe $i=0$ instead?

Comment: Its i=3 as the lower limit not 0. I'm confused on the factorial. Is the problem just 3!+2, so 5?

Comment: @kbball Please consider improving the title when you're editing a question. And please ask for confirmation before altering the content.

Comment: joey yes, but it isn't $5$.

Comment: $3!=3\times2\times1$

Comment: @Lord_Farin Can do. Thanks

Comment: @joey, you sure it's not $i=1$?

Answer (score 1):

$\sum\limits_{i=3}^3 z_i =z_3=3!+2=3*2*1+2=8$